# Avro nested type java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to

Tags: avro

When I try do decode Avro records with the following schema I get the following error:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"Example",
  "namespace":"com.example.test",
  "fields":[
    {
        "name":"nestedExample",
        "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"NestedExample",
            "namespace":"com.example.test.Example$",
            "fields":[]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to
>   com.example.test.Example$.NestedExample   at
>   com.example.test.Example.put(Example.java:40)     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.setField(GenericData.java:573)    at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.setField(GenericData.java:590)    at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)

This appears to be related to the namespace of the nested type. Note: this is how the Avro reflection specifies the namespace if reflection is used on a Java class with a nested class. If I change the namespace to be the same as Example then I can decode the records fine. **How can I decode records that have nested record types when the nested record types are in their own namespace?**

I am generating the Java classes using the Avro maven plugin. My Avro version is 1.7.7. Here is the code I am using to decode an Example record:

```
public class Avro_NestedRecord {

    List<Example> examples;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        examples = Arrays.asList(new Example[] {
                Example.newBuilder()
                .setNestedExample(new com.example.test.Example$.NestedExample())
                .build()
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void thisIsHowWeCodeSpecificRecordsDirectly() throws IOException {
        Schema schema = Example.getClassSchema();
        // write
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BinaryEncoder encoderInstance = EncoderFactory.get().directBinaryEncoder(outputStream, null);
        SpecificDatumWriter<Example> specificDatumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<Example>(schema);
        specificDatumWriter.write(examples.get(0), encoderInstance);
        // read
        ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
        BinaryDecoder decoderInstance = DecoderFactory.get().directBinaryDecoder(inStream, null);
        SpecificDatumReader<Example> specificDatumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<Example>(schema);
        specificDatumReader.read(null, decoderInstance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @natb1 you find any solution for this problem ?